# Access normal php file in cake php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

if i use normal php file so display error of controller missing
  and my normal php file is in order/api.php

in base directory
  so please help me how can i access this path without error

my htaccess code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{networkboost.net} !^/app/order/
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally If we need to use  normal file in cakephp

We need to store that file into the webroot folder of the cakephp.

And the way to access is

```
siteurl/filename.php
```

> Hope this will help you

Comment: Most welcome Sagar ! Everything is add on to open source community only.